# webview not loading url's with server address like(http://192.168.2.5: portnumber/index)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm loading some url's in webview , passing from listview, now url's with "www.com" working perfectly, but url's with ip address like (http://192.168.1.1:portaddress) not working and loading any app link in playstore.)

java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(compnieslist.this, webview.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://200.56.23.106:888/link/"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: first check if `http://200.56.23.106:888/link/` can be accessed from the device

Comment: What's your target API? http communication is restricted since API level 26. You have to use https. Have you got any errors in LogCat?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.technologies.corner.app.bijli.bill.wapda.wapdabill"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.4'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: but before few days ago they working perfactly

Comment: Vladslav Matviienko................  I have opened the links in browser...in browser it working